# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError while everything seems fine

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to work with a native library in java. The [vendor](http://neurosky.com) provided me with the appropriate java file (can be found [here](http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=app_notes_and_tutorials) under 'latest JNI implementation')

Furthermore i have set `-Djava.library.path="D:\*absolutePathToDLLFolder*"` and I tried a relative path too, with the same result.

Now when running my small app I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.neurosky.thinkgear.ThinkGear.GetDriverVersion()I
    at com.neurosky.thinkgear.ThinkGear.GetDriverVersion(Native Method)
    at eu.expandable.mindwave.Start.main(Start.java:23)
```

and here is my main-class:

```
package eu.expandable.mindwave;

import com.neurosky.thinkgear.ThinkGear;

/**
 *
 * @author Andre
 */
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Mindwave Test");

        //testing if os is 32bit
        //otherwise it wont work (under windows)
        int arc = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        if(arc != 32) {
            System.err.println("Sorry, only 32bit platforms are supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Mindwave Driver version: " + ThinkGear.GetDriverVersion());
        }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
            System.err.println("Are you sure the library is existing?");
            System.out.println("Will exit now");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println("Trying to build a connection...");
        int connID = ThinkGear.GetNewConnectionId();
        System.out.println("Done. Connection ID is: " + connID);



        System.out.println("Release connection");
        ThinkGear.FreeConnection(connID);
        System.out.println("Connection is freed");
        System.out.println("Exit");

    }

}
```

I would consider my code as correct, but for some reason it still crashes.
I am running under Windows 7 64bit and Java 8 (32bit).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PD procedure that might help you identify the problem.  I see you already check 32 vs 64 but I'm leaving that check in this procedure as it might help others at a later date.

Add the following to your program to identify the differences in the arch and load paths between the two runtime environments.  Investigate any differences in path/arch.

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

You can use the dumpbin.exe utility to identify the dependencies needed by the DLL that is being loaded.
Make sure the dependencies exist.
Example usage:

```
C:> dumpbin /imports your.dll 

Dump of file your.dll
File Type: DLL
  Section contains the following imports:
    **KERNEL32.dll**
```

You can use the where.exe command to find the location of the dependencies.
Example usage:

```
C:>where KERNEL32.dll
    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
```

If you see:

```
C:>where KERNEL32.dll
    INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)
```

Investigate why the dependent DLL is not on the path.

You can use the dumpbin.exe command to check 64bit vs 32bit.
Example:

```
C:>dumpbin /headers yourd.dll

 Dump of file yourd.dll
 PE signature found
 File Type: DLL
 FILE HEADER VALUES
         14C machine (x86)    <-- 32bit DLL

C:>dumpbin /headers yourd.dll

 Dump of file yourd.dll
 PE signature found
 File Type: DLL
 FILE HEADER VALUES
         8664 machine (x64)    <-- 64bit DLL
```

Investigate any 32bit vs 64bit mismatches between main/dependent.  If your JVM is 32bit, you need to use 32bit DLLs.  If your JVM is 64bit, you need to use 64bit DLLs.  ( It is okay to run a 32bit JVM on a 64bit OS but the JNI DLLs must be 32bit ( DLLs match the JVM not the OS ).

Comment: It's not a library loading problem. It's a method location problem. See the stack trace. No `load()` or `loadLibrary()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.neurosky.thinkgear.ThinkGear.GetDriverVersion()I

That means the library was found and the JVM is now trying to find that native *method* inside it. The issue here is that the method whose native signature is given above wasn't actually found in the library. You would have to post the .h and .c files of the library, at least the relevant method headers, to get further assistance. But you should run

```
javah com.neurosky.thinkgear.ThinkGear
```

and compare the newly-generated .h file with the one that's current in that project, and with its .c file.

Comment: Unfortunalty I can't prvide you with the c source as the manufractor doesN#t provide them